# How to display embedded image in a Qt WebKit

Tags: qt

I got some html page that I embedded as a resource file into my application. I can use `setHTML` to display it in a webkit in my application, but what if I wanted to include some image in that html?

Is there any simple way to access embedded images from Qt WebKit or do I have to copy the file somewhere to filesystem and dynamically update its URL in html source code?

Comment: Indeed, this is a duplicate, google results for my question didn't link to that though, so this should probably be kept as a redirect

Comment: You can click on the "Yes, thank you" button, and it It will still be kept as a redirect. Closed questions are not deleted, they are just marked as closed instead of unresolved/unanswered.

Comment: I don't see that button anywhere on this page